# Genymotion Error in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, genymotion

I am trying to install Genymotion, but I got this error:

> genymotion: error while loading shared libraries: libgstapp-0.10.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I had this problem because I didn t realize I download version fo Linux 32 bits  but I have 64 bits. In addtion, I have installed, before that, some librarys type libgstapp typing:     .

```
$sudo apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev
```

Genymotion runs after that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped to solve another software issue with "Meine CEWE FOTOWELT " Software (pre-production on-demand fotobook desktop software) on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 9):

I've run the command from Fernando Pie:

```
apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev
```

But I still got the error so, I found this that worked for me:

```
apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386
```